# Could connect to google cloud server via ssh only several times per IP, after that see “Connection timeout”

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I could connect google compute engine vm via ssh only several times (3 most likely) per single IP, after that I start constantly sees "`ssh: connect to host 111.111.111.111 port 22: Connection timed out`", but still could connect from different IP. What is the problem there and how could I fix it?

Comment: “Google cloud” encompasses a huge suite of products. Maybe you should clarify what you are actually doing with proper terminology. With that said, the only obvious answer is a firewall.

Comment: compute engine VM. I thought this is clear from tags assigned. But np, I edit the question

Comment: Have you checked fail2ban logs or CSF / LFD?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Sshguard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshguard) is involved in this case, you should take a look on the firewall rule because you IP may be was blocked.
You cab access your instance using the [serial port access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connecting_to_a_serial_console_with_a_login_prompt) then verify if your IP was blocked.